# MySQL Daily Appointment Scheduling Schema

Tags: html, mysql, database-schema, jsonschema

I am looking to create a booking system. On one end you have a client looking to book an appointment and on the other end you have a provider who has a schedule that a client can book against

When signing up as a provider they are allowed to pick their days of work and hours. They have html check-boxes which represent which days they can select and once they select a day the hours are are displayed (drop-downs in angular) as you can see below

[html schedule form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09QBW.png)

On the MySQL side I am thinking I can have a table which has a column for each day and have a comma separated list in there for the start time, end time, lunch time and lunch length

i.e. Provider selects Monday and Tuesday to work from the hours below

Provider 'Schedule' Table

```
|ScheduleID|ProviderID|Monday  |Tuesday |Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday|
|----------|----------|--------|--------|---------|--------|------|--------|------|
|1         | 2        |09:00am,|10:00am,|         |        |      |        |      |
|          |          |08:30pm,|07:00pm,|         |        |      |        |      |
|          |          |12:00pm,|01:00pm,|         |        |      |        |      |
|          |          |30 min  |60 min  |         |        |      |        |      |
|----------|----------|--------|--------|---------|--------|------|--------|------|
```

The table would have a schedule id and a provider id which links back to the "provider" table to link the provider to his schedule

Or is this better?

```
|-------------|-------------|----------|-----------|----------|------------|--------------|
| schedule_id | provider_id | week_day |start_time | end_time | lunch_time | lunch_length |
|-------------|-------------|----------|-----------|----------|------------|--------------|
| 1           | 1           | Monday   | 06:00 AM  | 08:00 PM | 12:30 PM   | 60           |
|-------------|-------------|----------|-----------|----------|------------|--------------|
| 2           | 1           | Friday   | 06:00 AM  | 08:00 PM | 12:30 PM   | 60           |
|-------------|-------------|----------|-----------|----------|------------|--------------|
| 3           | 2           | Tuesday  | 06:00 AM  | 08:00 PM | 12:30 PM   | 60           |
|-------------|-------------|----------|-----------|----------|------------|--------------|
```

if not post something that is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I go into how I believe you should structure your `Provider 'Schedule' Table`, please make sure to, *in the future*, remove fluff.

More on fluff [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions).

It may serve you better to make the following changes:

- make all column headers lowercase, as this might prevent errors if you attempt to query your database another way
- change `scheduleId` to `id`
- Instead of having seven columns, one for every day of the week, you could simply put a `weekDay` column that stores the value of that weekday
- Then create columns for `startTime`, `endTime`, `lunchTime` and `lunchLength`
- Finally, create a `scheduleId` column that ties together all the different weekday rows of someone's schedule to one provider

Some considerations:

- Instead of having strings `"Monday"` or `"Sunday"` in the `weekDay` column you could instead insert `0..6`, where `0` is a Sunday and `6` is a Saturday to make it more compatible with other languages
- You could always just keep `scheduleId` in this table and create another table with the individual schedule days and link them with a foreign key, but this might prove to cause more problems than it's worth
- Keeping that `lunchLength` as just an integer, as that will make everything easier

The reasoning behind splitting up the data as much as possible is because if you are querying using another language you might need to go through all the extra work of splitting those `Monday` and `Tuesday` columns if you just want the `startTime` for instance.

Hopefully the above is either a solution or allows you to consider another approach.

Comment: please look at my question. I added a section below which I think is what you meant. Let me know if this is what you meant. I think you meant if a provider is cutting say Mon - Fri he will have 5 different entries in that table and all 5 of those entries will have a unique schedule_id but will have the same provider_id pointing back to the Provider table

Comment: @figuer25 Because any answer to this question will require some opinion there is no right answer.  I gave a suggestion based on my experience with MySQL and what I thought might be helpful, as I don't know the best solution for you.

I am currently automating reporting using an OO language such as Ruby, so in my personal experience having such diverse information contained in one column (i.e. time stamps and durations in minutes) makes more work for me.  I also suggested utilizing more numerical id columns as these make for much quicker querying time (as opposed to searching by string).

Comment: @figuer25 One more thing: you might want to throw in a `week_day_id` column as I suggested in my answer.  In other words, if you wanted to query for everyone working on a `Tuesday` and your table had an infinite but countable number of rows, it would take a lot longer to search for the string `Tuesday` instead of the id `2`.  I also edited my answer to correctly reflect the Ruby Time class.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider the numeric substitution for speed but I have had logic already working with strings. I previously allowed a provider to enter his time for for every day. For example they would enter a time, say 9-5 and that was their schedule everyday. I am now updating it to give them a daily hourly option. But I will consider. I just do not like having to then have to map 0-6 with Sun-Sat etc

Comment: I decided to create reference tables for weekdays and some other data in my database tables. I was looking at potentially using ENUM but it seems there are some drawbacks as stated in this article http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Comment: @figuer25 Thank you for continually working on a solution to your problem and doing research.  I suggested utilizing an `ENUM` or `TINYINT` based on your application: a drop-down menu on a website.  Which will probably utilize [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) or [Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-i-wday).  Both utilize the `0..6` interval to represent Weekdays.  The article you referenced suggested that it was a good idea to use `ENUM` for concepts that will never change: such as the continents.  I would image the same holds true for weekdays.

Comment: @figuer25 You could also look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873551/mysql-daily-appointment-scheduling-schema/35875679?noredirect=1#comment59655607_35875679) SO question and [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6962/advantages-and-disadvantages-to-using-enum-vs-integer-types) DbA question for more reference.   Now the final decision is solely yours, and I hope you have all the tools necessary to complete your task now.  If not, keep the discussion going!

Comment: I think the limitations of ENUM push me away from it. In short it is simpler to use ENUM for weekdays and maybe for weekdays I will use ENUM since it literally has NEVER changed lol But I also have for example "member_type" as part of the user table which has values like "Client", "Provier" that list can expand so for that I will use a reference table. Overall I m ok with the extra joins to avoid future issues with expanding these "lists" I will update this post, most likely when I am done and know which approach I stuck with

Comment: @figuer25 Once again, I only suggested utilizing `ENUM` or `TINYINT` for the days of the week. This also means that, because you're working with Javascript, you never have to make that connection (i.e. `0` means Sunday) because JS already makes the connection between `0..6` and `Sunday..Saturday`.  It will eventually become clearer that storing days of the week in any other fashion would create extra work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java Android Library that you can convert into JavaScript: https://bitbucket.org/warwick/schedule_utils_demo/src/master/

Running the code in a client side language will save your server the burden as scheduling code is very inefficient.

Hope this helps.